# How to drawString in a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

i have this code which shows all the available fonts of the system but the fonts are many so i need to add a vertical scrollbar .
i searched and found i can make a JScrollPane and add it to frame but only for a JPanel.
So how can i draw the string of each font to a panel.
Sorry for my irrelevance but i'm new to Java.

```
public class FontList extends JPanel {
  static String[] families ;

  int[] styles = { Font.PLAIN, Font.ITALIC, Font.BOLD,
      Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD };

  String[] stylenames = { "Plain", "Italic", "Bold", "Bold Italic" };

  public static void setFamilies(String[] names){
      families = names;
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int f = 0; f < families.length; f++) { // for each family
      for (int s = 0; s < styles.length; s++) { // for each style
        Font font = new Font(families[f],styles[s],18); // create font
        g.setFont(font); // set font
        String name = families[f] + " " + stylenames[s]; // create name
        g.drawString(name, 20, (f * 4 + s + 1) * 20); // display name
      }
    }
  } 
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String[] fontNames = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      setFamilies(fontNames);
      f.add(new FontList());
      f.setSize(300,300);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `paint`, use `paintComponent`;
- Make a call to the super `paint` method you are using before doing any custom painting;
- Make use of `FontMetrics` for the current `Font` to determine size;
- Use `JLabe`ls instead

Take a look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html), [Measuring Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) and [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

In order to use a `JScrollPane`, the panel needs to be able to calculate its preferred size and return this via the `getPreferredSize` method. This needs to done before the component is painted.

Use `JLabel`s, it's much simpler